# Lotka-Volterra coordinates transformation

Tags: dynamical-systems, transformation, mathematical-modeling

I would like to ask the following:

Given a **Lotka-Volterra** predator-prey system,
\begin{align} 
& \frac{dx}{dt}={\alpha}x-{\beta}xy \\
& \frac{dy}{dt}=-{\gamma}y+{\delta}xy
\end{align}
, with all the parameters ${\alpha}, {\beta}, {\gamma}, {\delta}$ to be positive integers, I would like to apply a transformation in order to reach to the following form:
\begin{align}
& \frac{dx}{dt}=-{\mu_1}x(1-y) \\
& \frac{dy}{dt}={\mu_2}y(1-x)
\end{align}
where ${\mu_1},{\mu_2} \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Any ideas? 
Thank you all!

Comment: It is a part of an exercise for a course :/

Comment: See page 11: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~ma138/Spring15/mathematical_biology.pdf and this might be instructive: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75725/nondimensionalization-of-predator-prey-model

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} 
& \frac{dx}{dt}={\alpha}x-{\beta}xy \\
& \frac{dy}{dt}=-{\gamma}y+{\delta}xy
\end{align}
Let $x=kY$ and $y=hX$
\begin{align} 
& \frac{dY}{dt}={\alpha}Y-{h\beta}XY=\alpha Y (1-\frac{h\beta}{\alpha}X) \\
& \frac{dX}{dt}=-{\gamma}X+{k\delta}XY=-\gamma X (1-\frac{k\delta}{\gamma}Y)
\end{align}
With $\mu_2=\alpha \\ \mu_1=\gamma \\ h=\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \\ k=\frac{\gamma}{\delta}$

the wanted form is obtained :
\begin{align}
& \frac{dX}{dt}=-{\mu_1}X(1-Y) \\
& \frac{dY}{dt}={\mu_2}Y(1-X)
\end{align}

Comment: Correct! Thank you so much!

Comment: This does not answer the question, since both suggested parameters $\mu_1$ (as suggested in the answer) and $\mu_2$ (once a mistake in the answer is corrected) are negative although the exercise asks that they be positive. (And the formula for $\mu_2$ is wrong.)

Comment: I corrected my mistake. Thanks to Did to point it out.

Comment: And now that the solution is formally correct, what is severely lacking is an explanation for this change of variables. Note for example that the values of $h$ and $k$ (your notations) are quite obvious once one notes that one wants to send the original fixed point $(x,y)=(\gamma/\delta,\alpha/\beta)$ to the fixed point $(1,1)$ in the new system.