# nondimensionalization of system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at this set of PP equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{dR}{dt} & = \rho R\left[(K-R)-\frac{\beta F}{C+R}\right],\\
\frac{dF}{dt} & = \delta F\left[\frac{R}{C+R}-\alpha F\right].
\end{align}

My goal is to transform it into

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt}&=u(k-u-\frac{v}{1+u})\\
\frac{dv}{dt}&=bv(\frac{u}{1+u}-qv)
\end{align}

How do I find values of $q, b, q$
I know I should nondimensionalize but the algebra is not working out. I'm not sure how to nondimensionalize this system. Is there an elegant way?

well I make the subsitutions $r=r_s*r^*, f=f_s*f^*, t=t_s*t^*$. One gets  $$\frac{r_s}{t_s}\frac{dr*}{dt*}= \rho r_s*r^*(K-r_s*r^*)- \rho r_s*r^* \frac{\beta f_s*f^* }{C+r_s*r^*}$$  and also
$$\frac{f_s}{t_s}\frac{df*}{dt}=\delta f_s*f^* \frac{r_s*r^*}{C+r_s*r^*}-\delta f_s*f^* \alpha \delta (f_s*f^*)^2  $$

Even after getting rid of the coefficients on the far left of the equations I don't really see a clear way out

Comment: '.. but the algebra is not working out'. You should show us your working.

Comment: How far did you get? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75725/nondimensionalization-of-predator-prey-model) is a somewhat similar question; does that help?

Comment: It won't work unless $C\rho=1$.

Comment: With only scaling $R$ to $u$ and scaling $F$ to $v$, you can only get rid of two parameters from $\rho,K,\beta,C,\delta,\alpha$ so you can't get down to only three parameters $b,k,q$.  In particular, in the first equation, fixing the coefficient of $u^2$ will fix your scale of $R$ and you don't have the complete freedom to choose where the pole $R=-C$ get mapped to.  You need to add another freedom, e.g. scaling the $t$ too, to have some fighting chance.

Comment: I added a sliver of detail but can't get around simplifying the fractions so I can nondimensionalize cleanly

Answer (score 1):

Letting $R = r_{s} r^{*}, F = f_{s} f^{*}, t = t_{s} t^{*}$ as you did, the first equation becomes

\begin{align}
\frac{r_s}{t_s}\frac{dr*}{dt*} &= \rho r_s r^*(K-r_s r^*)- \rho r_s r^* \frac{\beta f_s f^* }{C + r_s r^*} \\
\implies \frac{dr*}{dt*} &= r^* \left[ \rho t_{s} (K-r_s r^*)- \rho t_{s} \frac{\beta f_s f^* }{C + r_s r^*} \right]
\end{align}

To match what you want, we need

$$r_{s} = C, \quad K = k C, \quad t_{s} = 1/(C \rho), \quad f_{s} = C^{2}/\beta$$

giving

$$\frac{dr*}{dt*} = r^* \left[ k - r^* - \frac{f^* }{1 + r^*} \right]$$

Similarly for the second ODE

\begin{align}
\frac{f_s}{t_s} \frac{df*}{dt^{*}} &= \delta f_s f^* \left[ \frac{r_s r^*}{C + r_s r^*} - \alpha  f_s f^* \right] \\
\implies \frac{df*}{dt^{*}} &= \delta t_s f^* \left[ \frac{r_s r^*}{C + r_s r^*} - \alpha  f_s f^* \right] \\
&= \delta \cdot \frac{1}{C\rho} f^* \left[ \frac{r^*}{1 + r^*} - \alpha \cdot \frac{C^{2}}{\beta} f^* \right]
\end{align}

To match what you want, we need

$$b = \delta/(C \rho), \quad q = (\alpha C^{2})/\beta$$

giving

$$\frac{df*}{dt^{*}} = b f^* \left[ \frac{r^*}{1 + r^*} - q f^* \right]$$

Now let $r^{*} = u$, $f^{*} = v$ and $t^{*} = t$ if you want to make the ODEs look exactly like the result you are after.

Comment: thanks. how did you get $t_s$ and $f_s$? I see how you got $b$ and $q$ but you needed earlier values to plug in. Also, how would we get this expression if I wasn't already given the answer beforehand that I had to try and match up. What's the thinking process behind it and what's the use of combinig parameters in this way besides making the ODE more tractable. Like how does this help in seeing which variables one can ignore?