# Nondimensionalizing a system of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

The following system of PDEs

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=\gamma(U-V)$$
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=\beta(V-U)$$
can be nondimensionalized by change of the independent variables to $\xi=\gamma x/c$ and $\tau=\beta(t-x/c)$, where $c$, $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are constants. This will give

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \xi}=U-V$$
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau}=V-U.$$

I am curious as to how exactly these new independent variables are determined. Is there a method or is it a mixture of practice and luck?

Edit: since both responses (thank you) say it is mainly experience, lets extend the question.

Is a simplification via substitution of new variables always possible? For example, if we were to add diffusion terms to both equations

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}-D_V\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}=\gamma(U-V)$$
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}-D_U\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}=\beta(V-U),$$
can we still make a useful substitution?

Comment: Experience. You have at your disposal scaling in time $t$, space $x$, and the $U$ and $V$. The nondimensionalization can be handy for simplifying the system, and also for understanding the influence of the size of the physical characteristics of the problem at hand.

Comment: The actual substitutions take experience and time to practice, but knowing the number of variables you will be left with at the end ahead of time is the [Buckingham Pi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem)

Comment: Just make a rescaling with unknown scaling factors, calculate the resulting system, and then determine a suitable choice of those factors in order to simplify things as much as possible. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75725/nondimensionalization-of-predator-prey-model), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a guess. I'll use the symbol $\sim$ to indicate that two quantities have the same dimension. If any two things are added together they must have the same dimension. The left-hand side of the first equation implies that $$c\sim L/T$$ (length over time). Equating the left and right implies $$\gamma\sim T^{-1}.$$ Similarly, $$\beta\sim T^{-1}.$$ Since $x$ is a length, you have just two choices for its non-dimensionalized version:
$$\xi=\frac\gamma cx\text{  or  }\xi=\frac{\beta}{c}x.$$ Similarly, for the time variable, we can take either $$\tau=\gamma t\text{ or }\tau=\beta t.$$ In total, you have four choices for the non-dimensionalization. Which one you pick should depend on what you are doing. For instance, taking the first choices above for $\xi$ and $\tau$, the equation becomes
\begin{align*}\partial_\tau V+\partial_\xi V=U-V\\\partial_\tau U=\frac{\beta}{\gamma}(V-U).\end{align*}
Note that the time shift as you write it is not related to dimensions, it's about changing coordinates to simplify the linear operator. Also note that this is a different non-dimensionalization than you achieved before since it involves the dimensionless quantity $\beta/\gamma$. One or the other might be preferred depending on the application (if you are doing something that has an application...). For example perhaps you want to study the regime $\beta\ll\gamma$.

As a side issue, to eliminate the transport part of the equation, you could let $\eta=\xi-\tau$ to obtain
\begin{align*}\partial_\tau V=U-V\\\partial_\tau U=\frac{\beta}{\gamma}(V-U).\end{align*}
Again, this is not a matter of dimensions; it's based on the observation that $\partial_\tau+\partial_\xi=(1,1)^T\cdot\nabla_{\tau,\xi}$ so we've chosen $\eta$ to satisfy
$$\nabla_{\tau,\xi}\eta\cdot(1,1)^T=0.$$
See any elementary treatment of transport equations for more details.

Edit: By adding more terms you've actually increased the number of possible non-dimensionalizations. Note that now $c/\gamma$, $c/\beta$, $(D_V/\gamma)^\frac12$, $(D_V/\beta)^\frac12$,... are all valid choices for the length scale.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for a choice that will simplify the equations but more importantly, completely eliminate all original independent variables. The second order diffusion terms tells me that the new variables should have at least one $x^2$, but for the combinations I've tried there is always an $x$ left somewhere in the new equations.